# Don't use constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code, I did not use `constructor ()`. I've always seen people use the constructor in class components, but even though I'm not using it in that code, it's working perfectly. In my code, putting the state outside the constructor, is it a good idea or would it be better to use the constructor with the state set inside it? Can it give some sort of error in the future, or worsen my system's performance doing so? What is more advisable to do in this case?

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import  {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import ActionCreator from '../redux/actionCreators'

import Button from '../elements/Button'

const statsgenre = {
'Ação': 'Action',
'Comédia': 'Comedy',
'Drama': 'Drama'
} 


const statsuser = {
'Assistido' : 'Watched',
'Assistindo': 'Watching',
'Assistir': 'Watch' 
}


class ScreensEditSeries extends Component{

state = {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    status: '',
    genre: '',
    notes: ''
}

componentDidMount = () => {    
    const serie  = {...this.props.match.params}
    this.props.load(serie)
    this.props.reset()
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(newProps, prevState){
    let serie = {}
    if (prevState.name === '' || prevState.name === undefined){  
        if (newProps.series.serie.name !== prevState.name){
            serie.name = newProps.series.serie.name
        }

        if (newProps.series.serie.genre !== prevState.genre){
            serie.genre = newProps.series.serie.genre
        }

        if (newProps.series.serie.status !== prevState.status){
            serie.status = newProps.series.serie.status
        }
        if (newProps.series.serie.notes !== prevState.notes){
            serie.notes = newProps.series.serie.notes
        }
        return serie
    }           
}

saveSeries = () => {
    const {name, status, genre, notes} = this.state
    const id = this.props.match.params.id
    const newSerie = {
        id,
        name,
        status,
        genre,
        notes
    }
    this.props.save(newSerie)
}

handleChange = field => event => {
    this.setState({[field] : event.target.value})
}

render(){
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="container">         
                <div>  
                    {this.props.series.saved  && <Redirect to={`/series/${this.props.match.params.genre}`}/>}
                    <h1 className='text-white'>Edit Série</h1>
                    {!this.props.series.isLoadding && <Button>
                        Name: <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange('name')} className="form-control" /><br />
                        Status: {<span>&nbsp;</span>} 
                        <select value={this.state.status} onChange={this.handleChange('status')}>
                            {Object.keys(statsuser)
                                .map( key => <option key={key}>{statsuser[key]}</option>)}
                        </select><br/><br/>
                        Genre: {<span>&nbsp;</span>} 
                        <select value={this.state.genre} onChange={this.handleChange('genre')}>
                            {Object.keys(statsgenre)
                                .map(key => <option key={key}>{statsgenre[key]}</option>)}
                        </select><br/><br/>
                        Notes: <textarea type='text' value={this.state.notes} onChange={this.handleChange('notes')} className="form-control"></textarea><br />
                        <button className="button button2" type="button" onClick={this.saveSeries}>Save</button>
                    </Button>}
                    {this.props.series.isLoadding && <p className='text-info'>Loading...</p>}
                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    series: state.series
}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
    load : serie => dispatch(ActionCreator.getSerieRequest(serie)),
    save: newSerie => dispatch(ActionCreator.updateSerieRequest(newSerie)),
    reset : () => dispatch(ActionCreator.seriesReset()),
}

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ScreensEditSeries)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should only use a constructor if you need logic when the class is first created, or if your setup depends on the props passed in. Since everything in your initial state is hardcoded not using a constructor is fine in this case.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem in using class components without a constructor. Usually you need it in case you have to do some work to prepare the state, process some props or other setup some instance variables as soon as the component is instantiated.

It's ok :)

Here, instead, there is a very interesting post from Dan Abramov about why, if you need to use the constructor, is needed to call `super(props)`:

https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/

Not super related to the question, but asking about constructor, I thought it could be useful to you.

Comment: @schu34, Matthew and 0xc14m1z Herbst, thanks guys, you helped a lot.. When i used bind, was really necessary to use constructor, but now, with arrow functions, i don't more need to use constructor, because i initialize the state in componentDidMount or getDerivedStateFromProps.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference. The reason you see most people doing it inside of the `constructor` is because doing `state = {}` directly on the class is new syntax that hasn't been widely adopted yet (it often still requires a Babel or similar transformation). See [`proposal-class-fields`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) for more information on it. One thing to note is that if you need to access any props to initialize the state, you have to do that in the `constructor`.